# How can I display a List/Array dynamically in only one DataGrid-Cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a RefItem with a list of Models. I want now to display the Description-Property of each model in one DataGrid-Cell like this:

> 35 hours, 10 hours, 3 hours

I firstly thought of a converter, but C# requires an IValueConverter, whereas the object-parameter is there only a string and theoretically, an IMultiValueConverter is required.

My DataGrid-Cell looks like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="txtScopeOfCare" Header="Scope of Care" 
IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding Path=CareModel.Description}" />
```

Of course, this Binding does not work, because it is a list.
Does someone have a clue how to achieve this? :)

Comment: Could you use String.Join(",", CareModel.Description)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create another property and bind to that?

```
public string Description => string.Join(",", CareModel.Select(c => c.Description));

<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="txtScopeOfCare" Header="Scope of Care" 
IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

I'm not sure what you are referring to as `a list`, if `Description` is the list, you can do this instead:

```
public string Description => string.Join(",", CareModel.Description);
```